# How can I Attach a .eml File Using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, eml

I am trying to attach a .eml file to my email that I am sending in PHPMailer. I am doing this right now:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment("/var/www/virtual/xxx.xxx.com/html/test_sample_message.eml", 'test.eml', 'base64', 'message/rfc822');
```

It does attach a .eml file, but it's always empty. Also, I tried doing this:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($body, 'test.eml', 'base64', 'message/rfc822');
```

Same result if I do that (the email file is attached, but it's empty).

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `addAttachment`? As per https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment, for addStringAttachment it says `This method can be used to attach ascii or binary data, such as a BLOB record from a database` - i.e. a string of data, not a file. `addAttachment` is for attaching ready-made files.

Comment: Hi ADyson - I tried using addAttachment, and it was the same result: a blank eml file was attached. Any ideas? (Don't know if it makes a difference, but I even changed the permissions on the eml file to be as least restrictive as possible.)

Comment: Check the return value from either call, don't assume it's working.

Comment: @Synchro - Are you referring to the result of addAttachment? I did this - $val = $mail->addAttachment("/var/www/virtual/beta.phishingbox.com/html/test_sample_message.eml");
                    print_r($val); exit("OUT");  -  and it returns true.

Comment: In that case I recommend setting a breakpoint and checking what happens when it reads the file after you call send(). Also check the SMTP transcript (set SMTPDebug = 2) so you can see exactly what is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($body, 'Original Email.eml', 'base64', 'application/octet-stream');
```

Answer (score 0):

delete code: `'eml' => 'message/rfc822'` in the function `_mime_types($ext = '')`

and then use the `addAttachment()`